# How to list the modified files?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am using [gitlab-ci](/questions/tagged/gitlab-ci) to run scripts defined in `.gitlab-ci.yml` whenever a PR is raised.

I want to get the list of modified files since the last commit.

The use case is to run file-specific integration tests in a large codebases.

Answer (score 21):

If you do not need to know the paths, but you simply need to run a specific job only when a specific file is changed, then use [`only`/`changes`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/21981) `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration, e.g.

```
docker build:
  script: docker build -t my-image:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG .
  only:
    changes:
      - Dockerfile
      - docker/scripts/*
```

Alternatively, if you need to get paths of the modified scripts, you can use [gitlab-ci](/questions/tagged/gitlab-ci) [`CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA` and `CI_COMMIT_SHA` environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/), e.g.

```
> git diff --name-only $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA $CI_COMMIT_SHA
src/countries/gb/homemcr.js
src/countries/gb/kinodigital.js
```

Comment: Please notice this feature only works from gitlab 11.4 onwards, thought it's good to mention for someone who's gonna run into it

Comment: `CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA` doesn't seem to be usefully--or tightly--specified enough for this to work all the time.  For example, the original question is about raising when a PR/MR is raised, so what you really need to know are the files changed within the MR, not just since the previous commit.

Comment: In my case I need to trigger something on changed files during merge to master so `CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA` is fine as it is defined as: "The previous latest commit present on a branch before a push request."

Comment: Warning: `CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA` is deceiving: let's say you just submitted version 10 of a series after a long review. Version 10 has only one file changed compared to version 9. In that case CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA points at version 9 and is basically useless (Tested with gitlab 11.10.2)

Comment: does `docker/scripts/*` include `docker/scripts/foo/bar`? i.e. do i need **/* to specify all folders recursively?

Comment: does `docker/scripts/*` include `docker/scripts/foo/bar`? i.e. do i need `**/*` to specify all folders recursively?

Answer (score 8):

A common use case that some people will find useful. Run the job when a merge request is raised. Specifically, run lint on all the files that are changed w.r.t. target branch.

As one of the answers suggest, we can get the target branch name through `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME` variable ([list of predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)). We can use `git diff --name-only origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME` to get the list of files that were changed. Then pass them on to the linter via `xargs`. The example configuration may look like.

```
code_quality:
  only:
    - merge_requests
  script:
    - git diff --name-only origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME | xargs <LINT_COMMAND_FOR_FILE>
```

Comment: It doesn't work when merge request source is a forked project.

Comment: Seems to return an error stating: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` Any idea how to fix this? Apparently the runner doesnt recognize what that branch path is. Works fine when  I run it localy

Comment: @Dellirium To me that seems like either a missing branch or conflicting branch name. On your local try listing all origin branches. `git fetch origin` and then `git branch`.

Make sure you have `master` branch in `origin`.

Comment: On my local, everything works, the command that is: `git diff --name-only origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME` (but obviously i replace the gitlab CI stuff with a string `master`) gives the list of files. When i run this on gitlab's pipeline, it simply says as i wrote above. So inside the CI the term `origin/master` is not recognized, as if the CI doesnt know what branches it has and doesnt know what `origin/master` means

Comment: A reason for `fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` might also be that you use git shallow clone. This is the default since Gitlab 12. Use `variables: GIT_DEPTH: 0` to fix it. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#git-shallow-clone for more information.